# Using a list inside a struct c++

Tags: c++, list, struct

I´m starting with the programming and i speak bad english sorry for that.

I like to use a list instead of an array, inside of a struct, something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

struct Market {
        string b;
        list <int> prices;
    };

int main()
{   list <int> precios;

    Market m1 = {"a",NULL};
    return 0;
}
```

but i get this error  conversion from `int' to non-scalar type std::list<int, std::allocator<int> >` requested|

Is this possible? maybe with malloc or free?

Comment: `prices` is not a pointer but it looks like you expect it to be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NULL` is not of the type `std::list<int>`, that's why you are getting this error.

Are you using a C++11 compiler?

If yes then try:

```
Market m1 = {"a", { NULL } };
```

Otherwise:

```
list<int> prices;
Market m1;
m1.b = "a";
m1.prices = prices;
```

Answer (score 3):

You should define a constructor

```
struct Market {

    Market(string val){b=val;}
    // or like this:
    // Market(string val):b(val){}
    string b;
    list <int> prices;
};
```

Then you will be able to create objects like:

```
Market a("A");
```

As lists default constructor creates empty list, you dont need to pass it any parametrs.

A good read about basics of classes: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/

Comment: He can do `m1 = {"A"};` as well but a constructor is much more desirable.

Comment: A better constructor: `Market(const std::string& val) : b(val) {}`

Comment: @MatthewLundberg, agreed. Prefer initialization lists to assignment in constructors.

Answer (score 0):

You are attemping to initialize the `list` with a null pointer value (actually an `int` type). If you need to store the list by value you can initialize 'm1' like so

```
Market m1 = {"a", std::list<int>()};
```